# Remove parents of the elements in Python Selenium

Tags: python

The HTML is located below, If the span value is less than 20%, then I want to remove the span child up until the `<div class="action">` parent only.

So for example:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 5% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the above HTML, these code should only be removed:

```
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 5% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So what should left is:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="info">

  </div>
</div>
```

This is my current python code:

```
items = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='content-name']")))
for item in items:
    percentage_text = re.findall("\d+", item.text)[0]
    if int(percentage_text) <= 20:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].remove();", item)
```

But it only removes the span class and not its parent.

Here is the full HTML, I think it needs javascript to remove elements but I am very new on javascript I researched for more than 2 hours and I still can't find solutions. Thank you very much.

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 5% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 95% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 32% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="action">
      <div class="content">
         <span class="content-name"> 15% </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're missing ' " ' on the class=content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get to the parent of the parent:

```
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].parentElement.parentElement.remove();", item)
```